# Make a attendance table for students with Go

Tags: go, net-http, go-http

I'm trying to create a Student Attendance web app. Currently have a struct

```
type Student struct {
    StudentID int
    StudentName string
    Created time.Time
}
```

All student will be listed on list.html

```
func ListStudent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    students := models.Student.ListAllUser()
    render.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "list.html", students)
}
```

list.html contain list of every students follows with Yes and No button for their attendance.

```
<p>#{{.StudentID}} {{.StudentName}}</p>
<a class="btn" role="button" href="/studentAttend/{{.StudentID}}">Yes</a>
<a class="btn" role="button" href="/studentAttend/{{.StudentID}}">No</a>
```

I'm struggle what the backend logic process to do with the button to store the students attendance. The idea is to have a request send to the server with Yes for True or No for False for student attendance that day.

The end goal is to have a table with row of students and column of each day of the month. The column day will have a tick for attend the school day and blank for the day absence along the student row.

Example how the table should look like: [image: Image Table]

Comment: The simplest way would be to add `?value=yes` and `?value=no` to the two html buttons' `href` attributes. Then your handler for the `/studentAttend/` path can retrieve the `value` query parameter from the request and do its logic based on that.

Comment: How can I relate the value with the day of the school attend ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to achieve your desired solution.
The question you should ask yourself is how much effort you want to invest.

One way (a bit more complex) could be, to implement an additional POST endpoint for the attendance of a student. For example:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/studentAttend/:studentID">
    <label for="not_attended">not attended</label>
    <input type="radio" name="attended" id="not_attended" value="false" checked />

    <label for="attended">attended</label>
    <input type="radio" name="attended" id="attended" value="true" />

    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

This example may require some javascript for the functionality, e.g. binding the submit event on the state of the radio's, add some AJAX to prevent a page reload, styling the two radios to a toggle switch... and so on.

Another way, as already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346849/make-a-attendance-table-for-students-with-go#comment131253646_74346849), is to add query parameters `/studentAttend/:studentID?value=<yes|no>` to your buttons.
Also here you could add some javascript to handle the request in the background.

---

Another thing I would change is the field names of the `Student` struct:

```golang
type Student struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Created time.Time
}
```

This is a more cleaner way when accessing the fields. Instead of e.g. `student.StudentName` you have `student.Name`.

Comment: The thing I am struggling to do is the logic backend after the button are submitted. I have edited original post